# grc.bashrc no such file or directory

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-lion

I am newbie to OSX, I tried to install bash, but when I running the terminal I got this error msg: `-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/grc/1.5/etc/grc.bashrc: No such file or directory`

so how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the output of `brew info grc`

```
grc: stable 1.5
http://korpus.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html
Conflicts with: cc65
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/grc.rb
==> Caveats
New shell sessions will start using GRC after you add this to your profile:
  source "`brew --prefix`/etc/grc.bashrc"
```

suggests you look for and remove from your `.bash_profile` file a line similar to the last line in the output above.

Comment: I got this `-bash: /usr/local/etc/grc.bashrc: No such file or directory`

Comment: I went to grcs's github page & it seems that it were last updated 1 year ago. Maybe you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where the shell (in my case zsh) had an error upon starting, which for me appeared after upgrading OS X.

The problem is that the brew command is called before the shell knows where the brew command is stored. To fix it, in your .bash_profile (or .zshrc) move this line:

```
source "`brew --prefix`/etc/grc.bashrc"
```

to be after this line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: NOTE: latest OSX has zsh built-in. You can add `source "\`brew --prefix\`/etc/grc.zsh"` in `~/.zprofile`